# VPC-running AWS Lambda sends SQS message only once

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, nat, amazon-vpc

I have a NodeJS Lambda function running in a private subnet, with allow all incoming/outgoing policies in both the security group and the NACL (not safe, but they do the job). The private subnet has a NAT gateway sitting in a public subnet of the same VPC, so internet connectivity works.

My goal is to send messages to an SQS queue.

The Lambda code is this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const sqs = new AWS.SQS()

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    sqs.sendMessage({
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify(event),
        QueueUrl: 'https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/000000000000/queue-name'
    }, function(err, data) {
        console.log(err, data);
        return callback(err, data);
    });
};
```

For some reason, this function only runs the first time in each private subnet I put it. After that it just times out.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2017-10-23T17:07:01.675Z 903aaabc-b814-11e7-a727-19816eaa468a Task timed out after 10.00 seconds"
}
```

And here's the log

```
START RequestId: 903aaabc-b814-11e7-a727-19816eaa468a Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 903aaabc-b814-11e7-a727-19816eaa468a
REPORT RequestId: 903aaabc-b814-11e7-a727-19816eaa468a  Duration: 10002.46 ms   Billed Duration: 10000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 32 MB  
2017-10-23T17:07:01.675Z 903aaabc-b814-11e7-a727-19816eaa468a Task timed out after 10.00 seconds
```

If I run the function unattached to a VPC, it works perfectly every time, but I must add some private resource access logic in there, so I can't run it outside of the VPC.

My feeling is that this has to do with the reusable container (infrastructure unit) that the function uses, but my experience with AWS in general and Lambda in particular is too shallow to figure out how that affects it.

I've tried the "warmer" version where the `sqs` object gets constructed in the `handler`, but that didn't work any better.

Does anyone have an idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try moving `sqs = new AWS.SQS()` into the `handler` function. I've seen the AWS SDK create a HTTP connection pool that runs into timeout issues when created outside the Lambda handler.

Comment: Global code does not run again if the container is hot. You need to re-initialize the global variables in your handler function.

Comment: How are you sure you have internet connectivity? It's incredibly easy to misconfigure your vpc with the nat gw etc.

Comment: Like I said, I already tried moving the initialization code in the handler. Same result: the function times out the second time it runs.

Comment: @Daniel it appears you're right, regular http requests time out as well. The problem was that the NACL specified inbound traffic is allowed on ports 80, 443 and 49152-65535 to the public network. It seems that the response was coming on a different port that was not open. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this was actually a connectivity issue.

I had 3 public subnets and 3 private ones. The public subnets routed traffic to `0.0.0.0/0` through an Internet Gateway (IGW). The private ones routed traffic to `0.0.0.0/0` through a NAT Gateway that was sitting in one of the public subnets.

The problem was that the NACLs attached to the public subnets only allowed inbound traffic on ports `80`, `443` and `49152-65535`. It seems that the request to the SQS service was coming on a different port than these.

I've allowed inbound traffic to the public subnets through ports `1024-65535` according to [the guide here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html#VPC_ACLs_Ephemeral_Ports), although it doesn't seem too secure.